# Screen tearing (very noticable during video playback) with HD3000 AND HD Radeon 6630m

Tags: video, radeon, thinkpad, tearing

I did not have this issue with Ubuntu 11.10. Well, to be clear, I did, but it was easily remedied with compiz workarounds.

I have tried both the propriety and open source ati drivers, and the intel HD 3000 (as far as I know) should be part of the Kernel already. So I am pretty much 100% stumped given my general lack of Linux knowledge. I really enjoy this OS, would hate to have to return to Windows (read: HATE) because of something as trivial as video playback.

Some details:

Lenovo Thinkpad Edge e520
Intel HD 3000/AMD HD Radeon 6630m

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

it's a nasty bug reported in https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37686 and also in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/755841

and it's still open!

Answer (score 0):

take a look here, maybe it will help you
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450

Comment: While this might help the user solve his issue, it is always a better idea to copy the relevant information for the sites you link and add a link to your answers pointing it to the source. Don not make 1 link answers, those are not recommend.